# Mobile quiz game Dev with Phaser-js and Cordova

Tags: cordova, phaser-framework

I developed a quiz game with Phaser-js and Cordova. In the opening game, there is a lag and the game adjusts to the size of the screen in small intervals. I wonder if anyone else had a similar problem. I used the following command in the boot file:

this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.edvinmz.NerdQuiz

Comment: I guess it's Phaser 2 (CE), if it's so I guess you have an `init()` method where you scale your game in the boot state, then maybe you're scaling it a second time maybe in the play state ?